# Debian 9 freezes when NetworkManager is active

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, debian-stretch

I have upgrade to debian 9 (from debian 8) and since then my system freezes when making traffic with wireless (for example browsing or watching youtube) and I have to turn off the PC.
Kernel is:

```
4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My desktop PC has a TPLINK TL-WN851ND wireless card which results using ath9k kernel module:

```
lspci -k
04:06.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k
```

If I turn off NetworkManager, my pc never freezes.

When NetworkManager is on, after some minutes (variable), my system freezes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an hardware failure on the wireless card.
I removed it and that problem disappeared.